# How to fade text when text is overflowed?

Tags: flutter

I'm having a problem with handling texts when they overflow. I've tried `overflow: TextOverflow.xxxx` ,`Expanded` and `Flexible` but it's still doesn't work. Can anyone help me with this situation?

```
class _FeaturedCardState extends State<FeaturedCard>{   
  @override   
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return InkWell(
      onTap: () {
        showToast(widget.name, context);
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.0),
        child: Container(
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 9,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Card(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
            elevation: 3.0,
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[

                Padding( 
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 20,
                    backgroundImage: AssetImage(widget.img),
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                  ),
                ),

                SizedBox(width: 10),

                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0),
                  child: Wrap(
                    direction: Axis.vertical,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      SizedBox(height: 2),

                      Text( 
                        widget.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 3),

                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[

                          Icon(
                            Icons.attach_money,
                            size: 11,
                          ),

                          Text(
                            widget.salary,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 10,
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                color: Colors.blue[300]
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),

                      SizedBox(height: 3),

                      Text( // This is the text that overflows
                        widget.desc,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      ),

                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ); 
}
```

I've searched a lot of atricles and it still doesn't help. If anyone could come up with a solution for this that'll be really great. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: You question isn't clear. Does [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13631) github issue seem similar to your problem..?

Comment: Try changing your parent Row widget by Wrap widget. If there is not enough space to fit the child, Wrap creates a new run adjacent to the existing children in the cross axis.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this,

```
class _FeaturedCardState extends State<FeaturedCard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
      child: Material(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        elevation: 3.0,
        child: InkWell(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
          onTap: (){
            showToast(widget.name, context);
          },
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 20,
                  backgroundImage: AssetImage(widget.img),
                  backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                ),
                const SizedBox(width: 10),
                Expanded(
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        widget.name,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 15,
                          color: Colors.blueGrey,
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 3),
                      Text(
                        "\u0024${widget.salary}", // Char code for $ symbol "\u0024"
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 10,
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          color: Colors.blue[300],
                        ),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 3),
                      Text(
                        // This is the text that overflows
                        widget.desc,
                        style: TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                          fontSize: 12,
                        ),
                        maxLines: 1,
                        softWrap: false,
                        overflow: TextOverflow.fade,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add your Text in Container and set static width for Container

for example:

```
Container(
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*0.7,
          child: Text( "xxxxx",),
        ),
```